# Javascript conflict in Bootstrap3 Remote Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use a bootstrap modal to display multiple tasks. The content in different, but the format is the same.
The problem is when i try to make my textareas editable with javascript. 
The code gets into conflict when i close and open the different tasks:

```
<!-- Module menu tree style -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// removing data from modal
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });

// new modal scripts
    $(document.body).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

        function getScript(url, success) {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url;
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                    done = false;
            // Attach handlers for all browsers
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                    done = true;
                    // callback function provided as param
                    success();
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    head.removeChild(script);
                }
                ;
            };
            head.appendChild(script);
        };

        getScript('{{ URL::asset('assets/js/summernote.min.js')}}', function () {

            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            } else {
                $('.summernote').summernote({
                    height: 150,                 // set editor height
                    minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
                    maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
                    focus: false,                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                    codemirror: { // codemirror options
                        theme: 'monokai'
                    },
                    toolbar: [
                        ['font', ["bold", "italic", "underline", "superscript", "subscript", "strikethrough", "clear"]],
                        ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                        ['color', ['color']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                        ['height', ['height']],
                        ['table', ['table']],
                        ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
                        ['view', ['codeview']],
                        ['help', ['help']]
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });

// summernote script for the first time i open the modal
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.summernote').summernote({
            height: 150,                 // set editor height
            minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
            maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
            focus: false,                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
            codemirror: { // codemirror options
                theme: 'monokai'
            },
            toolbar: [
                ['font', ["bold", "italic", "underline", "superscript", "subscript", "strikethrough", "clear"]],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['height', ['height']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
                ['view', ['codeview']],
                ['help', ['help']]
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
```

i tried using jQuery.noConflict() but it only makes it worse. Thanks

Comment: can you post HTML or create a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. turns out I over-complicated myself by using the  getScript(url, success)  function that I found online. Bootstrap modals work just fine by including the plugin's JavaScript file in the main page and the code that triggers the plugin, also in main page by using the following function:

```
// functions to clear the modals 
       $("#modalEditTask").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#modalEditTask").removeData('bs.modal');
    });
    $("#modalAddTaskModule").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#modalAddTaskModule").removeData('bs.modal');
    });

// functions to start the plugins
    $("#modalAddTaskModule").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        // call sumernote text editor
        jQuery('.summernote_new').summernote({
         ...
        });

        jQuery(".switchCheckBox").bootstrapSwitch();
    });
    $("#modalEditTask").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    ...
    });
```

WARNING!! if you use multiple modals like in the example above, you must call the function for every modal separately.

Also, every plugin you use, must be called in the "shown.bs.modal" function, even if it's called in the main layout or anywhere else. It will not work in your modal otherwise